# $4$ random digits, $2$ different ones.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, self-learning

I have been trying to solve the following problem

> What is the probability that among $4$ random digits, there appear exactly $2$ different ones?

Two different digits means that there should be two groups of $2$. There is $10$ possibilities for $2$ digits and another $9$ for the next two. But since this is an ordered solution, I thought that these numbers should be permuted as two pairs of indistinguishable objects. So my attempt for the required probability is

$$\frac{10\times 9\times \binom{4}{2}}{10^4}=0.054$$

This does not appear to be correct though. Could you please help me understand where I have gone wrong in the above?

Thank you.

Comment: Is 0011 an acceptable string?

Comment: @Jonny I suppose so, no explicit statement against that.

Comment: "Two different digits means that there should be two groups of 2." Does that mean 1333 is not acceptable?

Comment: @DPoole Oh this is my mistake, I didn't undestand the implications.

Comment: Also, there is a bit of over-counting above for the case where there are 2 numbers each appearing twice.

Comment: @DPoole Where does the over-counting come from?

Comment: Consider choose 6 to be one of the two numbers, then 7. Compare this with choosing 7 first, then 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $10^4$ equally likely digit strings of length $4$, all by assumption equally likely.  We want to count the "good" strings, the ones that have exactly $2$ different digits. It is actually a little easier to count the bad strings, but we will not take that path.

There are two types of good strings: (i) Strings that have $3$ occurrences of one digit, and $1$ occurrence of another digit and (ii) Strings that have $2$ of one kind and $2$ of another.

First we count (i). The digit we have $1$ of can be chosen in $10$ ways. It can be placed in any one of $4$ positions, and then the digit we have $3$ of can be chosen in $9$ ways, for a total of $(10)(4)(9)$.

Now we count (ii). The two digits we have one each of can be chosen in $\binom{10}{2}$ ways. For each such way, the position of $2$ occurrences of the smaller chosen digit can be chosen in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{10}{2}\binom{4}{2}$. 
Now add the results of (i) and (ii) and divide by $10^4$.

**Remark:** Note that counting (ii) is a bit tricky. It is all too easy to overcount by a factor of $2$.  Your calculation did exactly that, and did not deal with the Type (i) possibilities.

Comment: Oh I see it it now, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. As to the double counting, after one does it a couple of times, one gets sensitized to the possibility and it stops happening.

Comment: If I may steal a little bit more of your time, how would we adapt this problem in the case of three different digits, still out of four? It seems to me that the probability in this case would be $$\frac{\binom{10}{3}\times 3 \times 4}{10^4}$$ That is, choose the three different digits out of the ten, multiply by the ways one can choose the value of the fourth digit( which has to be  of the same value as one of the three) and the number of possible arrangements. Would that be correct?

Comment: Sorry about lateness in replying, I was away.  Your analysis is almost fine. The number of possible arrangements, however, is $\binom{4}{2}2!=12$, not $4$. Another way: Choose the doubled digit, $10$ ways. Choose where they will go, $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Now fill the two empty spaces with different digits, $(9)(8)$ ways.

Comment: Thank you, once again. Your way is much more intuitive. What is the rationale behind the factor $\binom{4}{2} 2!$ though?

Comment: Your $\binom{10}{3}$ counts the number of ways to choose the numbers we will use, and to choose who we will have $2$ of. Choose where the doubled digit will go, this can be done in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Then the other two digits can be placed in the empty spots in $2!$ ways. Or else imagine that we paint the digits we have two of blue and red. There are then $4!$ wyas to arrange them. Now bleach out the colour. Then the number of arrangements gets divided by $2$, and so there are $\frac{4!}{2}$ of them.

Comment: Of course, it all makes sense now. Combinatorics is fun. Thank you again.

Comment: There are still other ways of counting. The smallest non-doubled digit can be placed in $4$ ways. For each way the larger non-doubled digit can be placed in $3$ ways, and now it's over. Yes, combinatorics is fun. So are all the other branches of mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the two different digits, where $0 \leq X < Y \leq 9$ (so order matters). Then the possibilities are:
$$
XXXY, XXYX, XYXX, YXXX,\\
XXYY, XYXY, XYYX, YXXY, YXYX, YYXX,\\
XYYY, YXYY, YYXY, YYYX
$$
So the numerator of your fraction should be:
$$
\binom{10}{2} \cdot \left[ \binom{4}{1} + \binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{3} \right]
= 630
$$

Comment: I completely missed one case, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Numbers of ways to get exactly 1, 2, 3, or 4 distinct digits are: 10, 630, 4320, and 5040, respectively.